# What are the options like to let users see / type Russian text under Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, language

I'm working on a computer to give away. The best of all possible outcomes would be complete translation of everything in the UI. The real outcome I'd like to achieve is besides displaying Cyrillic correctly, the user could type in English or Cyrillic (using the standard Russian layout, not the QWERTY-derived phonetic layout) and be able to easily switch between the two. (The computer is running Windows 7 Professional, so that appears to close the "Open the control panel and follow your nose" avenue of solutions.)

What options are available? The most promising option I was able to see was [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/7lp32sp1.html), which someone claimed as working with sub-Windows-7-Ultimate systems. I was wondering what would be available where the goal is not total UI i18n/l10n, but more modestly to let the user switch between Russian and English letters as desired.

Comment: Windows 7 Professional only allows for a single language pack to be installed

Comment: Windows Professional, *left to its own devices*, does not do this itself. Vistalizator does.

Comment: This thread is confusing.  You mention Vistalizator in the question and at least imply that it isn't the solution.  Then you self answer with that as the solution.

Comment: I had no intent to imply *knowledge* that Vistalizator was not the solution; I was intending to articulate my *ignorance* as to whether Vistalizator really adds value or is broken or ineffective in my situation. There is a difference.

Answer (score -1):

[Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/) is meant to provide an open source tool to do just that.

It was a minor headache to install, and I did not initially know that *first* [download and install Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/download.html) and then you may be able to install Microsoft language packs, but now I have a Windows 7 Professional computer that mostly speaks Russian.